# Codeigniter - undefined property error calling model from controller file

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I have an error with the following file, and specifically, I assume, the following line:

```
$data['events'] = $this->homes->get_events();
```

**The error is:**

```
 Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$homes
```

I am in the controller file, where I assume the problem is.

**File name: /application/controllers/Home.php**

$data['events'] = $this->homes->get_events();    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function _construct()
        {

        parent::_construct();
        $this->load->model('homes');
        }

    public function index()
    {
$data['events'] = $this->homes->get_events();
$this->load->view('template/header.php');       
$this->load->view('home/index.php', $data);
$this->load->view('template/footer.php');
    }
}
```

There is a model file at models/Homes

We tried changing the name of the model file to 'homes' (lower case) and also the code to 'Homes', but the same error persisted.

**Specifically the error on running the url is:**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$homes

Filename: controllers/Home.php

Line Number: 15

Backtrace:

File: public_html/anchor/application/controllers/Home.php
Line: 15
Function: _error_handler

File: /public_html/anchor/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: Isn't `_construct` actually `__construct`( with 2 underscores) ?

Comment: Just changed that and tried - same error. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Also in `parent::_construct();`. Not sure if it makes a diff., but trying to fix that too.

Comment: Ah - tried that and it works now!

Comment: Indeed because constructor wasn't called properly. Nice it got fixed, voting to close now.

Comment: shouldn't it remain open to perhaps help someone...or too trivial>

Comment: Technically it's trivial as issues caused by typos don't really add up to purpose of SO.